# Recursive copy of a binary tree

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

I don't understand why this method copy the binary tree, it works but it looks strange because it doesn't use any method to insert nodes, thank you.

```
public BinaryTree<E> copy(BinaryTree<E> T, Position<E> v)
    {
        BinaryTree<E> S = new LinkedBinaryTree<E>();
        if (T.hasRight(v)) 
           copy(T, T.right(v));         // recurse on left child
        if (T.hasLeft(v))
          copy(T, T.left(v));   // recurse on right child
        return S;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedBinaryTree<String> T = new LinkedBinaryTree<String>();
        Position<String> r = T.addRoot("r");
        Position<String> a = T.insertLeft(r, "a");
        Position<String> b = T.insertRight(r, "b");
        Position<String> c = T.insertLeft(a, "c");
        Position<String> e = T.insertRight(b,"e");
        Position<String> f = T.insertLeft(b,"f");
        Position<String> g = T.insertRight(a,"g");
        Position<String> h = T.insertLeft(g,"h");
        Position<String> i = T.insertRight(g,"i");

                BinaryTree<String> A = T.copy(T, r);
        A.treeprint(A, r);
        System.out.println("...................");
        System.out.println("isempty: "+A.isEmpty()); //true
        System.out.println(A.left(r).element()); //a
        System.out.println(A.right(r).element()); //b
}
```

Comment: That method does not, and cannot work.

Comment: it works, this is strange.

Comment: The method creates and returns an empty LinkedBinaryTree, it never uses S. Please provide a small test that shows it 'working'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method does not work.

Your test constructs a tree 'T', uses your copy method (Which creates an empty tree 'A').

You then show that A is empty: Correct, it has no nodes.

The reason that A.left(r).element() shows a is because you are passing left() the root of the tree T.

I believe there is nothing in your code that checks whether r is in A when you call A.left(r).